# Como renderizar con php atraves de v8JS el siguiente codigo

Tags: php, rss

Tengo instalada en PHP la extensión v8js, quisiera saber como renderizar al lado del servidor. Se que en v8js no existe lo que es el DOM ni tampoco el objeto Window. Entonces quisiera saber como se hace la renderizacion en el servidor, tomando como ejemplo el siguiente código.

JS (main.js)

```
function comment_insert(data, ul_id) {

  let t = `
    <li class="comment-holder" id="${data.comment_id}">
      <div class="user-img">'
        <img src="${data.profile_img}" class="user-img-pic">
      </div>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <h3 class="username-field">${data.username}</h3>
        <div class="comment-text">${data.comment}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-buttons-holder">
        <ul>
          <li class="delete-btn">[x]</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>`;

    elem = document.getElementById(ul_id);
    elem.insertBefore(t);  
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

$source = file_get_contents('./main.js');

$v8 = new V8Js();
$v8->executeString($source);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <ul id="box"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```